# Facebook Graph API explorer gives error code 100 for certain event ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to pull the data for the following Facebook Event: 1438916099678479

(https://www.facebook.com/events/1438916099678479)

When I enter the Facebook ID in the Graph API explorer however I get the following error:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=1438916099678479

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request.", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

The event however is open and I can't see what the reason is I'm not able to pull the data, with other events it works fine.

Comment: That's because the event itself doesn't exist.

Comment: Maybe this is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664786/does-facebooks-graph-api-allow-access-to-all-photos